# Symfony 3.3: Undefined class constant HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR

Tags: php, symfony

I am working on a Symfony 3.3 based application. I have my project locally installed and installed on a server. My laptop and server are both running Ubuntu 16.04.

On my local machine the prod and dev are both error-free. However when I want to visit the prod on the server I get the following messages in my var/logs/prod.log

> php.CRITICAL: Undefined class constant 'HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR' {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Undefined class constant 'HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR' at /home/webwijs/birdbook/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Fragment/InlineFragmentRenderer.php:122)"} []
>
> request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: "Undefined class constant 'HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR'" at /home/webwijs/birdbook/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Fragment/InlineFragmentRenderer.php line 122 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Undefined class constant 'HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR' at /home/webwijs/birdbook/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Fragment/InlineFragmentRenderer.php:122)"} []

It might be important to know that it is an installation upgraded from symfony 3.1.

Comment: I think there are more things that are missing in your question so we can give you a good answer. try running the application locally in production mode and see the errors. It might be possible to have the error because of other custom packages that you use in vendor directory.

Comment: Looks like your deployed installation is broken, because the `HttpFoundation\Request` class should have that constant. Let me guess … your build process includes pulling a git repo and running  `composer install`. But you didn't upgrade your `composer.lock` before building. Is that plausible?

Comment: @MariusBogdan As I wrote in my question the production environment runs error free on my local machine.

Comment: @lxg You are right about the composer install part. However I did run composer update on my local machine and my composer.lock file is part of the git repository. This means it gets updated on git pull. --edit __I checked the modification date of the composer.lock file and it is indeed up to date__

Comment: @lxg to be sure I ran composer update on the server and cleared production cache.

Comment: I also removed the vendor directory on the server and ran composer install again to be sure all files are good.

Comment: I did find out that the default FOSUserbundle routes like /login and /register also are working without errors!! It is all the other routes from my own bundle that give a 500 error on the page and the messages in the log.

Comment: @JorisWagter: Can you check that the file of the `Request` class is identical to this one? https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.3/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php

Comment: @lxg I compared my local and server Request class files to the one on github (with Meld). They are identical.

Comment: If I can't get it to work at all I will remove the entire project from the server. Then clone and deploy a fresh install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same issue.

Basically I dump the Request filepath and it was the old one from SF3.2 loaded from the var/bootstrap.php.cache loaded instead of the new one in Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request.

Just remove your var/bootstrap.php.cache file then clear your cache and everything will be fine.

Comment: Wouldn't that imply that there is something else broken in the OP's build or configuration ? Because `composer install` should have a post hook cleaning caches, right ?

Comment: Yes it should clear the bootstrap.php.cache, I really don't know what happened in this case.

Anyway we have an answer for the next time if something similar happen.